# renamed index.js in React and it failed

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new to react and I renamed index.js to app.js and it failed to build.I am curious about the fact as react gets to know that it is looking for a file named index.js.I created the app using create react-app as on docs.Is there any way to run it with a changed name?

Comment: Change the src of your script tag in your index.html

Comment: i couldn't get it working .i don't think this is how it works .

Answer (score 0):

to add config changes you need run [*eject*](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) command. Then in config/paths.js (appIndexJs) you can setup entry point. But think do you really need it? (keep in mind - this is one way operation)